# Can we configure local and azure servers in a WSFC for Always On Availability Group?

Tags: availability-groups, clustering, azure-vm

Can we configure a local server and an azure server as a two node cluster for Always on Availability Group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can

I've had 2 local (on-premise) SQL Servers and 1 VM in Azure, configured in Availability Group of three servers

Comment: The process to configure WSFC for Availability Group is same as we follow for two local servers right?